# can't include processing.js sketch to use and display phpmyadmin database images

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, processing, processing.js

I have a site written in PHP, with a database through MySQL and PHPMyAdmin. I'm trying to use a Processing sketch to apply effects on the images users upload to their account. I have included the base processing.js file, but the sketch won't appear on my site. Edit: I'm also running everything locally with XAMPP.

This is the file structure on the database:

**phplogin**(database) >
**accounts**(table) which contains:

```
id username password    email          upload 
1  test     (encrypted) test@test.com  [test.png]
```

This is the Processing sketch, which I took from a tutorial to attempt to display the images, so it is most probably wrong:

```
MySQL msql;
import de.bezier.data.sql.*;
import de.bezier.data.sql.mapper.*;

String dbHost = "localhost"; 
String dbPort = ""; 
String dbUser = "root"; 
String dbPass = "";  
String dbName = "phplogin";
String tableName = "accounts"; 

PImage displayimg;


void setup()
{
  msql = new MySQL( this, dbHost + ":" + dbPort, dbName, dbUser, dbPass );

  if (msql.connect()) {
    // get number of rows
    msql.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName);
    msql.next();
    println("Number of rows: " + msql.getInt(1));
    println();

    // access table
    msql.query("SELECT * FROM " + tableName);
    while (msql.next()){
      // replace "first_name" and "last_name" with column names from your table
      String s1 = msql.getString("username");
      String s2 = msql.getString("upload");
      println(s1 + " " + s2);
    }

 }
  size (400, 300);
  displayimg = loadImage(".$upload");
}

void draw()
{
   image (displayimg, 0, 0);
   tint(255, 127);
   image (displayimg, 0, 0);
}
```

And this is the php code that includes the sketch through processing.js, and another attempt to just display images through php.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit();
}
$DATABASE_HOST = 'localhost';
$DATABASE_USER = 'root';
$DATABASE_PASS = '';
$DATABASE_NAME = 'phplogin';
$con = mysqli_connect($DATABASE_HOST, $DATABASE_USER, $DATABASE_PASS, $DATABASE_NAME);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Home</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body class="loggedin">
        <nav class="navtop">
            <div>
                <h1>imagine</h1>
                <a href="profile.php"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>Profile</a>
                <a href="logout.php"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Logout</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Colaborative Art Project</h2>

            <p>Welcome, <?=$_SESSION['name']?>! Upload an image and take a look at the art piece you've contributed to:</p>
            <?php
            include("upload.php");
            ?>          
        </div>

        <?php $dir='images/';
        $img = "SELECT upload FROM accounts";

        $result = $con ->query ($img) or die ($con -> error);
        while ($row = $result ->fetch_assoc ())
        {
            $int_image = $row["upload"];
        } ?>

        <script type ="text/javascript" src="processing.js"></script>

        <canvas id ="imagine" data-processing-sources="imagine.pde"></canvas>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

If anyone could point out how I can make this work at a barebones level just so I could play around with Processing image effects with the images users upload, that'd be great. The idea is to display the images on top of each other on the home page to make a colaborative art piece. If you're going to recommend P5js please do so in a way I can implement it simply. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to run your Processing code on the client or on the server? Processing.js only works client-side, but you're using code that only works server-side.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that. I'm running the database locally through XAMPP to PHPMyAdmin, if that matters, nothing is uploaded anywhere. What part exactly is coded for server-side only? @KevinWorkman

Comment: What the point of mixing NodeJS with PHP?

Comment: Also please note that Processing.js was discontinued back in December of 2018, but even back then, it most definitely couldn't run any code with `import` statements (because JS doesn't understand compiled java bytecode).

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a client side technology (Processing Java / Processing.js / p5.js ) on the server side by the looks of it and mixing languages along the way.

If you want users to upload images to a server then that server to create a collage, that collage would need to be implmented on the server side.

Given you are using PHP you have a few (mostly built-in) options available:

- for a basic collage you could use [ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php): [montage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.montageimage.php) could be pretty useful
- if you want to also draw shapes (e.g. rectangles/ellipses/arcs/lines/etc. a-la Processing) check out the [php GD library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

You might want to have a script that over a period of time renders a new collage/collaborative piece so it's cached and keeps the server happy.
This composited image could simply be downloaded when users want to view it.